# VLC installation on Lucid

Tags: installation, apt, vlc, add-apt-repository

Environment : Lucid Lynx (Ubuntu 10.04)

I had installed VLC 1.0.6 using the following:

```
% sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lucid-bleed/ppa
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-pulse mozilla-plugin-vlc
```

After a month or so, While updating via command line, I got a notification stating a lot of packages were automatically installed and hence I should uses `apt-get --autoremove` which I used. Now VLC was uninstalled in this. And now when I try to install VLC back, I getting the following error:

```
root@srihari-laptop:~# apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1.1.13-1~ppa1~lucid1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I have tried to do every thing possible including purging the packages but that didn't work out. I need VLC to work. Please let me know how do I fix this.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 reached it's EOL (End of life) soon ago. I would consider upgrading. In fact, this error has probaly happend because of the version is so old.

Comment: I use ZTE Communications' Data Card that works with Reliance service. The problem is this device installs it's own network software and is not controlled by the ubuntu network manager. Now the binary package auto stored in this device works fine with Lucid but shows errors with precise.

Comment: @nerof61 I don't see why this would happen because it's so old--**it hasn't reached EoL yet.** At the end of this month, 10.04 will be EoL for desktop use. (I certainly agree that anyone running 10.04 on the desktop should upgrade. But being *near* end-of-life doesn't break anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this PPA:
https://launchpad.net/~nvidia-vdpau/+archive/cutting-edge-multimedia/+packages

It provides VLC and FFMPEG, so dependencies should work. Of course, remove the other PPA.

Comment: Synaptic doesn't show that any package is broken at all. This error comes up when I install using command line. While installing `vlc` via Synaptic, I get a dependency error that
`vlc-nox` will not be installed. If I try to install `vlc-nox` first, then I get `libavformat52` which in turn gives me `libavcodec52` which in turn asks `libavcodec52`  >= 1.0.6 but installed version is 1.0.4

Comment: E: Broken packages -> that is why I was thinking about broken packages.

Comment: Srihari, can you tell me if it works with this PPA?

Comment: Ttoine, thanks that worked.

I removed the ffmpeg and vlc ppas(https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg) (https://launchpad.net/~lucid-bleed/+archive/ppa) and uninstalled `libavformat52` v 1.0.6. After I reloaded, I got the right versions for everything. And then `vlc` install worked.